# PyO3 convert rust struct to PyObject

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I have a simple class annotated with `#[pyclass]`

```
#[pyclass]
pub struct A {
    ...
}
```

Now I have a function of the form

```
fn f(slf: Py<Self>) -> PyObject{
   //... some code here
   let output = A{...};
   output.to_object()   // Error: method `to_object` not found for this
}
```

Should I annotate my struct with something to make it derive `pyo3::ToPyObject`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have power over the function signature, you can just change it to `fn f(slf: Py<Self>) -> A`

I prefer this method, wherever possible, because then the conversion just happens under the hood.

If you need to keep the signature general because you might be returning structs of different types, you need to invoke the correct conversion method.

A struct marked with `#[pyclass]` will have `IntoPy<PyObject>` implemented, but the conversion method isn't called `to_object` but rather `into_py`, and it wants a gil token. So here's what you do:

```rust
fn f(slf: Py<Self>) -> PyObject {
  //... some code here
  let gil = Python::acquire_gil()?;
  let py = gil.python();
  output.into_py(py)
}
```